# Bootstrap is wrong version in my rails project

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, rbenv

I am going through a rails Udemy course, and we are using bootstrap. The instructor is on an older version and I started using the most recent version. Before long I discovered they are very different, so I wanted to switch to the correct version for the project. I have done gem uninstall gem bootstrap, and rails assets:clean, and went as far as to switch back to main and delete that git branch.  I then updated the gemfile to install bootstrap 4.0.0, and ran bundle install.  Gemfile lock reflects the changes.  I then copied the instructors provided source files for the views we had been working on and the application.scss file.  It has not worked.  The scss in the rails app is being completely overridden by some trace of bootstrap 5.2.  I know this because I inspected the page in the chrome dev console and in the sources there is this link which references the version.

> /* line 1, ../../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootstrap-5.2.0/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_root.scss */

I have restarted the rails server multiple times, but there is no effect.  I have navigated to that folder in the rbenv directory and the bootstrap-4.0.0.alpha6 version is listed there, not the 5.2.0.  However, the 5.2.0 version is persisting in what is on the browser. No changes that I make in the scss file have any effect.  I tried changing all the colors to random ones, but none show up.  There are no error messages to share.  The CSS simply has no effect and appears to be overridden by this file that I cannot find anywhere in my rails project or on my system.  Thank your for any guidance to fix this.

Comment: Have you considered creating a new user and installing the correct version for that user - ie clean.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean... also to clarify, this is not on on Heroku or anything.  I'm just viewing at at localhost:3000.

Comment: On Windows, you can have multiple user accounts. On Mac OS X the same. Linux as well. On Unix, Irix etc again multiple user accounts. But not heard of Heroku - is that a Greek monument?

Comment: are there any css files in app/assets/builds/ ? if so, delete them

Comment: www.heroku.com  it's a hosting service commonly used for smaller rails applications because it's easy to get it working.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Les.  There is not a builds folder under assets in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.. I had to use rake assets:clobber to clear out precompiled files that had the bootstrap 5.2.0 in them.  I did that and then rake assets:precompile and it instantly fixed it.